# How to trigger a notification from the command line in OSX Yosemite?

Tags: macos, notifications, osx-yosemite

Is there a native-way in OSX to trigger a notification, other than using https://github.com/julienXX/terminal-notifier?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

It is possible with:

```
osascript -e 'display notification "Notification text" with title "Title"'
```

For more customization check [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115373) answer.

Comment: how do I give it a variable? when I use something like ${1} instead of Notification text it prints exactly "${1}" instead of the value of variable.

Comment: @MohammadGanji  It's likely a shell quoting issue.  Try using `osascript -e "display notification \"${1}\" with title \"${2}\""` instead.